# Type error ' ... has no properties in common with type IntrinsicAttributes while converting js file to tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm heavily stuck in converting js file into typescript(tsx).

Here is the error during the conversion. the error is occurred on rendering components such as
<Register {...props}/>, <Register {...props}/>}, <Page404 {...props}/> and so on.

```
Type '{ history: History<unknown>; location: Location<unknown>; match: match<{}>; staticContext?: StaticContext | undefined; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

This is my whole js file. and I also googled and tried importing RouteComponentProps
but it didn't work for my code.

Please give me some advice to solve my problem.

App.tsx

```
import React, { Component, FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import './scss/style.scss';
import { photoSelector, getPhotos } from "./redux/features/photos/Photoslice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";


interface State {};

type Props = { component: FunctionComponent} & RouteComponentProps;

type isAny = {
  component: Component;
  rest: any
}


const isAuthenticated = () => {

  if(localStorage.getItem('token')) return true;

  return false;
}

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ component  , ...rest } : isAny)  => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    !isAuthenticated()
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/' />
  )} />
);


const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component  , ...rest } : isAny)  => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    isAuthenticated()
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
);


// Containers
const TheLayout  = React.lazy(() => import('./components/TheLayout'));

// Pages
const Login  = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/login/Login'));
const Register = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/register/Register'));
const Page404  = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/page404/Page404'));
const Page500  = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/page500/Page500'));


const App: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = () => {


  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { photos, loading, errors } = useSelector(photoSelector);

  console.log(photos, loading, errors);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPhotos());
  }, [dispatch]);

  //<PrivateRoute exact component={TheLayout} path="/"/>
  // <Route path="/"  render={props => ( isAuthenticated() ? <TheLayout {...props}/> : <Redirect to='/login' /> )} />

    return (
  
        <HashRouter>
            <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
              <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login" render={props =>  <Login {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/register"  render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/404"  render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/500"  render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
                <Route path="/"  render={props => ( isAuthenticated ? <TheLayout {...props}/> : <Redirect to='/login' /> )} />
              </Switch>
            </React.Suspense>
        </HashRouter>
   
    );

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to wrap your `lazy` components in `React.Suspense` before you try to mount them

```
<Route exact path="/register"  render={props => <React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading</div>}><Register {...props}/></React.Suspense>} />
```

Either add this to yor routes or import the components statically